# How to increase javascript loop delay with easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, intervals, easing

I need to count up from 1 to 60 but i want to count up with an easing, so for example it would go from 1 to 30 with a 100ms delay, after that i need to increase the delay so the counting will gradually slow down when it reaches 60. This is what i got so far(not much):

```
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    i += 1;
    console.log(i);
    if(i == 60) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xfCg/1/ ?

Comment: almost, but i need to slow down with an easing, like an animation: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `setTimeout()`, something like this:

```
var delay = 100, count = 0;
function delayed () {
    count += 1;
    console.log(count);
    if (count > 30) {
        delay += 10;
    }
    if (count < 60) {
        setTimeout(delayed, delay);
    }
}
delayed();
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDXLn/).

Answer (score 3):

Why not slow down continuously? Looks much nicer in my opinion. I updated the answer of @Teemu accordingly. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDXLn/1/).

```
var delay = 0, count = 0;
function delayed () {
    count += 1;
    console.log(count);
    //adjust to influence overall speed
    delay+=5; 
    if (count <60) {
        setTimeout(delayed, delay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something you can use. A bit of mathematics in action

```
var i = 0, a = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    i += 1;
    a = parseInt(Math.log(i)*Math.log(i)*100, 10);
    print(i, a);
    if(i == 60) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 100);

function print(i, a){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
    },a);
}
```

Basically, the value of `a` will increase gradually. You can observe very minor difference in time the count of `i` prints